# Why is using 'push' inside createSlice add '3' to my state instead of appending an array?

Tags: redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I am trying to append action.payload to my state. However, push methods adds action.payload.length to my state instead of appending the entire array! What am I doing wrong?

```
const initialState = { users: [] };

export const usersSlice = createSlice({
  //other code.
  ,
  extraReducers(builder) {
    builder.addCase(fetchUsers.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
      console.log(current(state));
      state.users = state.users.push(...action.payload);
      console.log(action.payload);
      console.log(current(state));
      // this one works.
      // state.users = state.users.concat(action.payload);
    });
  },
});

// selector
export const selectUserById = (state, userId) =>
  state.users.users.find((user) => user.id === userId);
```

This is the error I get (referring to selector):

```
TypeError: state.users.users.find is not a function
```

And this is my console:

```
// This is my state.
{
    "users": []
}


// this is action.payload. Which is an array of 3 objects.
[
    {
        obj1
    },
    {
        obj2
    },
    {
        obj3
    }
]

// This is the state after using push:
{
    "users": 3
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, such a silly mistake.

As y'all know, `push` method does not return anything. Thus, it made no sense for me to try to assign it to my state. `concat` method on the other hand, returns a new array. That's why it worked.

Here is what I changed:

```
state.users.push(...action.payload);
```

There is not `state.users =` anymore.